# Error: AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'sqrt'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import numpy as np
np. sqrt(3)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-029a7ac454da> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 np. sqrt(3)

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

I know it's basic but please guide. I am new to python 3.

Comment: Delete spaces between `np.sqrt(3)`

Comment: @yagizcandegirmenci - works for me **with** the space in a python shell.

Comment: I dont know why it worked for me tho **with** spaces

Comment: thanks but problem still the same

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have a file named `numpy.py` in your workspace.

```
(test-py38) gino:test$ touch numpy.py
(test-py38) gino:test$ ll
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 gino gino 0  6月 10 12:30 numpy.py

(test-py38) gino:test$ ipython
Python 3.8.3 (default, May 14 2020, 20:11:43) 
...

In [1]: import numpy as np 

In [2]: np. sqrt(3)                                                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-54486447ed79> in <module>
----> 1 np. sqrt(3)

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

You **must not** have files named after Python packages because `import` will import *your* file instead of the *actual* package. You **need** to rename them to something else.

See the [Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) docs for info how Python imports stuff:

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the variable [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

You could also check that it's importing the correct package by printing `__path__`:

```
(test-py38) gino:test$ ipython
Python 3.8.3 (default, May 14 2020, 20:11:43) 
...

In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.__path__                                                                                                     
Out[2]: ['/path/to/.venvs/test-py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy']

In [4]: np.  sqrt(3)     # The spaces don't matter                                                                      
Out[4]: 1.7320508075688772
```